# Showing the category hierarchy as clicked in WordPress, with image and desc

Tags: categories, pages, link-category

have a very weared issue, i am sure the solution is simple but i am not very used to wordpress and cant figure this out.

what i have is a WordPress theme and if needed i can change it to any other docent mater.

**what i have is**

i have some category in my wordpress and they have child and the child has child it goes to 4 lavels.
like

```
Book
-Novel
--book name
---chapter 1
---chapter 2

Article 
-about life
--life article 1
--life article 2
```

etc etc this is just a simple example.

**Now What i want is**

> i want to show the list of main categories with its image and
>   description on the home page and when clicked on a category show its
>   child and when clicked on a child show its child on next page and so
>   on. at the end the final post.

also for category image i have added a plugin called category image in wordpress.

i have tried to show the list of categories on home page with the help of some plugin, like this `[categories]` this short code helps to show the list of categories but i also want to show the image, description and the hierarchy when clicked.

i will be really happy if any one can give me any advice, help or any suggestion. i am still working will post here for any progress. Thankx

**What i am looking for is**

> When clicked on fiction category open all the books in that category
>   and then when clicked on a book name open all the chapters and then
>   when clicked on a chapter open the post

[image]

> what i need is i think very simple, just a hierarchy of category when
>   clicked. like if i click on novel all the books in novel category
>   should open and then when i click on any book all the chapters of the
>   book should open and then clicked on chapter the post should open.**

Comment: Can you rephrase. reword what you're trying to do? It's a very long sentence and it's extremely difficult to follow. Use the edit link to update your question

Comment: i am trying to do something like this, when some one clicks on a category, a new page opens with its sub categories and then some one clicks on sub vategory a new page opens with sub sub category and then some one clicks on sub sub category the post/article of that sub sub category opens and then when clicked on the post it opens the post in a new page.

Comment: That's an even longer sentence than the original one, I don't understand. Please use the _edit_ link under the question to edit your question to clarify. If you can describe it using something other than words, examples, screenshots.

Comment: It seems that you want to do something if use in ajax will have a better result and I have answered a post with the ajax example similar to your screenshots. You may refer to [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/363147/how-to-get-dynamically-custom-post-type-that-are-under-a-certain-category/363151#363151) to see if it helps first.